# Picasa Web Albums API : getting X latest uploaded photos using Atom

Tags: picasa, google-photos

I'm trying to fetch the latest X uploaded photos of specific user but can't get the actual photos although I received a success response from Google.

This is the URL i'm using: https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/xxxxxx/?max-results=10&alt=json

Am I doing something wrong? or this API is broken and I must take the albums approach by first finding all albums and then start fetching required number of photos?

Thanks